# Where does Minecraft for Windows 10 store its data?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have searched in `%appdata%`, pulling up the list of files there, but there is no file labelled `.minecraft`. Searching `%appdata%\.minecraft` returns "no results found".

I also opened Minecraft to click on the resources button and could not locate that either.

Comment: You're not using the XBox version on a computer. I don't know what you're using, but definitely not that.

Comment: You need to specify if you are referring to Minecraft : Java Edition, or Minecraft : Windows 10 Edition. A quick way to check... did you use the Microsoft store to buy Minecraft?

Comment: @galacticninja Just to keep myself informed: why did you edit this question? Is improving closed questions still beneficial?

Comment: @Joachim I saw this question in the reopen votes review queue. I decided to edit it from there (which also casts a reopen vote). Yes, it is beneficial to improve closed questions to get their quality up for reopening.

Answer (score 38):

The Bedrock (Windows Store/Windows 10) version of Minecraft folder is not `%appdata%/.minecraft` like the Java version.

For the Win 10 version you need to go to:

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

See [the official Mojang help](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1480874-where-are-minecraft-files-stored-) for more info.

Comment: I am sure I am using Bedrock edition, But there is no `Packages` folder inside `%AppData%`.

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis it is in `%LocalAppData%`

Comment: I have spotted my mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Crazy how hard this information was to find. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Found mine in *c:\users[my_user]\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves*.
I am using the Java edition, on Windows 10 (version 1909).

Comment: But the question is for Bedrock Edition. How does a Java Edition answer help for a question about Bedrock Edition?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 : It's not obvious that "Minecraft for Windows 10" is the Bedrock edition, but then there's also "Minecraft: Java Edition," which runs on Win 10, but doesn't note the OS in the title. It's confusing, so Joachim was understandably confused.

Comment: @EJMak The question’s tags clearly state that the asker is on Bedrock Edition. Also note that Joachim was the last *editor* of the post, not the original poster of the answer. The original poster is Vince LeAudet, read the usercards more carefully.